# wordpress 3.5.1 upgrade: admin panel not working properly

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I have just updated a clients site to wordpress 3.5.1. Install went fine and I reinstalled all the plugins which also seemed to work fine, and the front end of the website is working, however there seems to be a number of errors with the back end admin.

- Side panel expanding menus are not working. You have to click on the menu header (eg Plugins) before it will open up.
- Widget admin area is not working at all. I can't remove or edit any of my current widgets

The problem still occurs when all the plugins are deactivated. I've been searching the web for an answer, but can't find one.

Please help

Thanks you

Comment: You need to [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) this. But, if you deactivated all plugins, the probability is high that the theme is responsable.

Comment: Got a similar problem too. It was an ajax problem for me. Disable your plugins one by one and see for each action how it goes. You can also use the web inspector of chrome / firefox to see if there are any troubles in the 'Console' tab. My admin was missing the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php file. In my case the WP-Stats-Dashboard plugin was messing up the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can try,

1. Go to /wp-admin/update-core.php and try "Re-install Now"
2. Download latest.zip from WordPress.org and FTP it up manually
3. Another thing that may have happened is the database borked. Make a backup of the database through phpmyadmin, then go in and **Repair and Optimize.**

There could be any number of issues going on with your instance, but from what you describe, I am leaning towards a database issue where the broken tables need to be repaired. Good luck.